# Prove that $\operatorname{Ext}^{d+1}(A, B)\cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(M_d,B)$

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

So, given a resolution, with $P_{i}$ projective modules: $$0\longrightarrow M_d\longrightarrow P_{d-1} \longrightarrow \cdots \longrightarrow P_0 \longrightarrow A\longrightarrow 0,$$ I'm trying to prove that $\operatorname{EXT}^{d+1}(A, B)\cong \operatorname{EXT}^1(M_d,B)$(Weibel, pg 93). The thing is that, if I've get the functor correctly, we first of all  apply $\operatorname{Hom}(-,B)$ and so we have: $$0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(P_0,B)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(P_1,B)\longrightarrow\cdots\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(M_d,B)\longrightarrow 0$$

Now we have to make the homology asociated with $P_i$ to obtain $\operatorname{EXT}^i(A,B)$, but I'm stuck here. What do I do to see that isomorphism? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Choose a projective resolution$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}$ $$\cdots\to Q_1\to Q_0 \to M_d\to 0$$ of $M_d$.

Then the sequence $$\cdots\to Q_1\to Q_0\to P_{d-1}\to P_{d-2}\to \cdots \to P_0\to A\to 0$$
is exact (prove it), hence a projective resolution of $A$. Compute the $(d+1)$-th $\Ext$-group of $A$ with that resolution and then compute the first $\Ext$-group of $M_d$ with the above resolution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Proceed by induction on the length of the resolution to prove that, for any $i\ge1$, one has
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}\Ext^{d+i}(A,B)\simeq\Ext^i(M_d,B).$$

For the inductive step, split a resolution of length $d+1$:
$$0\to M_{d+1}\to P_d\to P_{d-1}\to\dots\to P_0\to A\to 0 \tag{1}$$
into the short exact  sequence $\;0\to M_{d-1}\to P_d\to M_{d-1}\to 0$, and the shorter resolution:
$$0\to M_d\to P_{d-1}\to\dots\to P_0\to A\to 0,$$
where $M_{d-1}=\operatorname{Im}(P_d\to P_{d-1})$.
Then use the inductive hypothesis and the long homology sequence deduced from $(1)$ to show that, for all $i\ge 1$,
$$\Ext^{d+1+i}(A,B)\simeq\Ext^i(M_d,B).$$

Comment: So first I need to prove it in the case of $d=1$. But how? Wouldn't I need to make a resolution of $M_{1}$ first, apply $EXT^1 (M_{1},B)$ and  calculate $EXT^1(A,B)$ an see if they are isomorphic? But how i find this resolution?

Comment: You have to consider the long homology sequence and use that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(P,B)=0$ for all $i>0$ if $P$ is projective.